# Excel 2010 Pull certain text from a string after &REQNO=

Tags: regex, string, excel, pull

I am having trouble pulling text from a cell that is a long web address. It varies in length but the text I'm after always follows `&REQNO=`.  It's a number that looks like `ABC-ABC-2015-0001`.  I would like to use Visual Basic for this and was trying the regex capabilities to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("&REQNO=",A1)+LEN("&REQNO="),9999)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  It seems to work, but it is pulling the data after my string as well.  Is there a way to cut it off after a certain amount of characters?

Comment: I fixed it, I changed the 9999 to 17 and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for the quick reply!